# Histograms intersection point - Python

Tags: python, histogram, intersection

I have two histograms generated with

```
plt.figure(figsize=(30,10))

sns.set()
sns.distplot(A, hist=True, kde=True, bins=50, color = 'darkgrey', hist_kws={'edgecolor':'white'}, kde_kws={'linewidth': 3})
sns.distplot(B, hist=True, kde=True, bins=50, color = 'lightgreen', hist_kws={'edgecolor':'white'}, kde_kws={'linewidth': 3})

plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.title("A vs B")
```

Now I need to find the coordinates of the intersection point between the two histograms, any idea about how can I do that?

[histograms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axVd6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Histograms don't really have "intersections" per se because they are discrete binned distributions. However, you could approximate each histogram with a continuous probability distribution (this would require you to know the distribution type of the data though, e.g. normal, lognormal). With continuous probability distribution functions (pdfs), you could then set these pdfs equal to one another and solve for the intersection.

The discrete analog would be to identify the bin or bins at which the two distributions intersect (i.e. histogram A is greater than histogram B in bin 10-20, and less than histogram B in bin 20-30, so the "actual" continuous pdfs intersect somewhere within the range 10-30. Then, you could use some form of interpolation to estimate the exact intersection. The easiest but not necessarily the most accurate interpolation strategy would be linear interpolation.